# C# - Troubleshoot .net Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have created new windows service to send an email. It is working properly in my local and Test environment but when we deployed into UAT server it is getting stopped after sometime. Even If we restart the service, again it is getting stopped.

And the server is handled by different team. So unable to find exact root cause. Is there any possibility, to troubleshoot if it is deployed in server?

Comment: What does the Event Viewer say?

Comment: Do you have any logs you can check?

Comment: @john server team didn't share event log. Also we are logging from code but there is no information in it. for time being is there any other option available to troubleshoot?

Comment: Demand the event logs from the server team. If they won't give then you won't fix.

Comment: Tell Operations you have better things to do than to inspect half-reported production issues

Comment: Is that possible to write a manual log to capture the line of code which causes the service to stop from running. if possible can you please share any reference link.

Comment: Can be a missing dependency, DLL or whatever prevent your service to start, so your logs won't be available and only the event logs will help you.